# Removing delimiters

Tags: python, perl, shell

I have a file looking like this:

```
('chr1', '1499102', '1500297')
('chr1', '1811177', '1812131')
('chr1', '2312420', '2313646')
('chr1', '6683999', '6684724')
```

N number of rows.

I want to print it like this:

```
chr1 (tab) 1499102 (tab) 1500297
```

Any one liner shell or python or perl.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using python:

```
for line in open('filename'): print('%s\t%s\t%s'%(eval(line)))
```

*(of course, you need to pass this one-line python script to the python interpreter: `python -c "..."`)*

the `eval()` function is not safe and should be considered "evil" if you are going to process unverified user input through it. if this function is a real threat to you, you can use this version, which is much more restrictive with its input:

```
import ast
for line in open('filename'):
    print('%s\t%s\t%s'%(ast.literal_eval(line)))
```

*([here](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is the documentation for `ast.literal_eval()`)*

Comment: It is good to know what exactly eval does http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval (hint: it's not really safe)

Comment: @rplnt: yes, i do know that eval() is not safe at all. the OP asked for a one-liner and that's the easiest one, which perfectly suits the need for a one-off processing. however, i will edit the code to include a much safer version...

Answer (score 8):

```
perl -nE '$,="\t"; say eval' file.txt
```

Making use of perl's output record separator, `$,` to provide the tabs. `eval` should be safe to use on single quoted strings, and is probably the best option.

Comment: Nice and clever evaluation of every single line as valid Perl code.

Answer (score 4):

Perl one-liner here ^_^

```
cat file.txt | perl -ni -e "printf qq{%s\t%s\t%s\n}, m/'([^']+)'/g;"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe "s/\('(.*)', \'([0-9]*)', '([0-9]*)'\)/$1\t$2\t$3/g" yourfile
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

Would sed/awk work for you, too?

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' your_file_with_stuff_in_it | sed "s/[')(,]//g"
```

Comment: If you use `sed` anyway, why not go all the way. `sed -e "s/', '/\t/" -e "s/^\\('//" -e "s/'\\)$//" your_file_with_stuff_in_it`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F "'" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $2, $4, $6}' FILE
```